# polarArea Chart: disable data on startup

Tags: chart.js

I am using the polarArea chart and would like to disable certain labels by default. Is it possible that they are disabled at startup but can be re-enabled later by a user click?

Here is my example:
https://jsfiddle.net/r0b67max/

```js
var options = {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: {
  labels: ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'],
    label: 'Dataset 1', // die zweite und dritte Datenpunkte sind standardmäßig deaktiviert
  }]
}
}
```

At startup the label 4 should be deactivated.

i tried the hidden attribute in the dataset. however, this disabled the entire dataset and not individual values.
hidden as array is always evaluated as true here

Comment: I see you are using Chart.js version 2.3 (in jsfiddle). There is a way but you need to have an higher version of chart.js, leveraging on "toogleVisibility" API.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer!
What version exactly do I need?
And how must the configuration look like?

Comment: I would suggest to use version 4.x (latest major) but I think the API was implemented in 3 (I don't know exactly in which minor). After chart creation, invoke (chart = chart instance created before) chart.toggleDataVisibility(3); chart.update();

Comment: Hey @user2057925, thanks for your help and sorry for the late feedback.
it works!

Comment: you can still deposit your solution as an answer then I can also mark this accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use version 4.x (latest major) but I think the API https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#toggledatavisibility-index was implemented in v3 (I don't know exactly in which minor).

Having an updated Chart.js version, after chart creation, invoke (chart = chart instance created before)

```
chart.toggleDataVisibility(3); 
chart.update();
```